# Using .reproject for resampling/interpolation of 10m Sentinel-2 bands into 20m

Tags: sentinel-2

Is it the right method of resampling/interpolating 10m bands of Sentinel-2 into 20m bands?

```js
/*-----Loading Sentinel-2 Level-2A (SR) Data-----*/

var tiles = ['42QVM', '42QUM', '42RUN', '42RTN', '42RTP', '41RQJ', '41RPJ', '41RPH', '41RNJ', '41RNH', '41RMH', '41RLH'];

var ImageryCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .select('B[2-8]', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12')
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', tiles))
  .filterDate(2018-12-14, 2022+'-12-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20));

/*-----Upscaling (Interpolation) of Bands (B2, B3, B4, B8)-----*/

var UpscalingFunction = function(image2){
  var selectivebands = image2.select('B[2-4]','B8');
  var upscaling = selectivebands.reproject({crs: 'EPSG:32641', scale: 20});
  return image2.addBands(upscaling);
};

var Upscaling_Total = ImageryCollection.map(UpscalingFunction);
```

**Note:** EPSG:32641 is the original projection system.

Comment: Your objective is not clear. Do you want interpolation and resampling at the same time? And did you try the code in GEE?

Comment: I just want to aggregate the 10m pixels into 20m pixels so that I will get all the bands in same 20m resolution. Yes, I have run it in GEE and it is performing well. I just want to be sure that I am doing this correctly.